# Best practise for multiple screen resolutions support

Tags: android, screen-resolution, android-screen-support

I would like to know what is the best practice to set UI layout that supports different type of screen resolutions on Android. Is there any lib which facilitates the work ?
Thanks in advance for your replys and have a good day :)

Comment: I am pretty sure Android manages that automatically and it's already been coded by Google. *That or I didn't quite understand your question.*

Answer (score 0):

There's no prepared solutions for this task, it depends on your app structure and goals. e.g look at GMail app: on small screen, list of emails and one email are fragments on separate screens, but on tablet both fragments are present on screen at same time.

These [articles](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) are also very helpful